# VS Android Emulator error in preparing virtual machine: XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android, visual-studio-emulator

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise. The VS Android emulator does not pass "preparing virtual machine", and gives an error when I try to execute it.

I already:

- Check that Hyper-V services is running and restarted the service just in case.
- [I check that the path in Regedit is correct to my Android SDK.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ks7a.png)
- My Android SDK is up to date.
- [I check that I have downloaded the API from SDK Manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDVcA.png)

Here is the log:

```
> 3> 12/4/2016 10:13:57 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/4/2016 10:13:57 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:03 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:03 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:03 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:03 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:10 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:10 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:10 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:10 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:10 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/4/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 0> 12/4/2016 10:15:59 PM : [Informational]
===== Session Ended ===== 0> 12/4/2016 10:50:44 PM : [Informational] ===== Session Started ===== 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:44 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:44 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:44 PM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT
10.0.10240.0 Windows 10 Pro 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: unknown 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: cnd5142np9 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: 2248 1> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family, Version: 10.18.15.4268 2> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles. 2> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 3 Platforms: 2 2> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles. 2> 12/4/2016 10:50:45 PM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5 3> 12/4/2016 10:50:50 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 3> 12/4/2016 10:50:50 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone 3> 12/4/2016 10:50:50 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3> 12/4/2016 10:50:50 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/4/2016 10:50:50 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/4/2016 10:51:01 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/4/2016 10:51:01 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/4/2016 10:51:01 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/4/2016 10:51:01 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 0> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational]
===== Session Started ===== 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT
10.0.10240.0 Windows 10 Pro 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: unknown 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: cnd5142np9 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: 2248 1> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family, Version: 10.18.15.4268 2> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 3 Platforms: 2 2> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 12:04:19 AM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:24 AM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:24 AM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:24 AM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:24 AM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:24 AM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:37 AM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:37 AM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:37 AM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5 /video "1080x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_KitKat_(4.4)_XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/5/2016 12:04:37 AM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 0> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational]
===== Session Started ===== 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT
10.0.10240.0 Windows 10 Pro 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: unknown 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: cnd5142np9 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:18 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: 2248 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:19 AM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family, Version: 10.18.15.4268 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:19 AM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:19 AM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 3 Platforms: 2 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:19 AM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:19 AM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5 0> 12/5/2016 11:41:28 AM : [Informational]
===== Session Ended ===== 0> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] ===== Session Started ===== 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT
10.0.10240.0 Windows 10 Pro 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: unknown 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: cnd5142np9 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: 2248 1> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family, Version: 10.18.15.4268 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 3 Platforms: 2 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:58 AM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 11:41:59 AM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:03 AM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:03 AM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:03 AM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:03 AM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:03 AM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:22 AM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:22 AM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:22 AM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/5/2016 11:42:22 AM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:38 AM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:38 AM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:38 AM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:38 AM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:38 AM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:42 AM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' device. 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:42 AM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:42 AM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5 /video "1080x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_KitKat_(4.4)_XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 4> 12/5/2016 11:42:42 AM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 0> 12/5/2016 1:57:35 PM : [Informational]
===== Session Ended ===== 0> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] ===== Session Started ===== 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT
10.0.10240.0 Windows 10 Pro 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: unknown 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: cnd5142np9 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: 2248 1> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family, Version: 10.18.15.4268 2> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 3 Platforms: 2 2> 12/5/2016 4:31:55 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles. 2> 12/5/2016 4:31:56 PM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:00 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:00 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:00 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:00 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:00 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:11 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:11 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:11 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/5/2016 4:32:11 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:01 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:01 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:01 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:01 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:01 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:07 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:07 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:07 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/5/2016 4:37:07 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:49 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device... 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:49 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:49 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments... 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:49 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running... 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:49 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine... 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:55 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device. 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:55 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:55 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\avirgili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.avirgili" /noStart /silent 3> 12/5/2016 4:40:55 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13)
```

Comment: The logs show "XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning". Verify that your system meets the [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx), then work through the steps mentioned in the [VS Android emulator troubleshooting guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Anchor_6). You can inspect the Event Viewer for any Hypervisor errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the visual studio android emulator and the visual studio as an admin

Comment: Thanks for the quickly response, i already run vs as an admin but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get the answer to my problem, i didn't install some stuff of the visual studio, to be more specific "Silverlight Development kit", "Windows 8.1 Tools".
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwifp.png)

Silly of me.

Now is working fine.